# Detecting if input string has a space

Tags: c++

I wrote this code to detect if an input string has a space or not. Please tell what is wrong in this approach.

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
using namespace std;

int main(){
    string inp;
    getline(cin, inp);


    for (int i = 0; i < inp.length(); i++) {
        string z = to_string(inp[i]);
        if (z == " ") {
            cout << "space";
        }
        else {
            i++;
        }
    }
}
```

If i enter a string with spaces, it doesn't print "space".

Comment: There is no need for incrementing "i" in the else clause. What are your results without it? It may be skipping the spaces altogether.

Comment: Answer given already, you might still want to consider `std::find(inp.begin(), inp.end(), ' ')` – and if you don't want to, you might consider a range based for loop: `for(auto c : inp) { if(c == ' ') ...`.

Comment: @Aconcagua `std::string` has its own `find()` method: `inp.find(' ')`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Since `inp` is an `std::string`, `inp[i]` will be a `char`. Since [`std::to_string`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/to_string) only has overloads for arithmetic, non-char values, calling it on a char  is akin to calling it on the integer representation of said char. (If you log `z`, you'll likely find a number printed.)

Instead, directly compare `inp[i]` to a space.  `else { i++; }` is also unnecessary – you may be jumping over spaces.

```
for (int i = 0; i < inp.length(); i++) {
    if (inp[i] == ' ') {    // note single quotes for char
        cout << "space";
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

@TrebledJ's answer explains why your code is broken and how to fix it.

Another way to handle this situation is to use `std::string::find()` instead:

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

int main(){
    std::string inp;
    std::getline(std::cin, inp);

    if (inp.find(' ') != std::string::npos) {
        std::cout << "space";
    }
}
```

Alternatively, your original code tries to output `"space"` for each space character found.  You could use `find()` in a loop:

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

int main(){
    std::string inp;
    std::getline(std::cin, inp);

    std::string::size_type idx = inp.find(' ');
    while (idx != std::string::npos) {
        std::cout << "space at " << idx << std::endl;
        idx = inp.find(' ', idx+1);
    }
}
```